Problems with using "stop_words" in tibble, tidytext
I got a problem with using "stop_words".
What I tried is;
tibble(text = word_space) %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word,
                input = text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)

And the error message is;
ncol(corpus) >= 2 is not TRUE
> 

Additional info is below.
This is how "word_space" is made of;
word_space <- cam %>%
  unnest_tokens(input=value,
                output = word,
                token = "words")

word_space <- word_space %>%
  count(word, sort = T)

The "word_space" has only one column and it's character.
This is how the "word_space" looks like;
> word_space
# A tibble: 33,592 × 1
   word     
   <chr>    
 1 hello    
 2 thank    
 3 you      
 4 for      
 5 coming   
 6 for      
 7 the      
 8 focus    
 9 group    
10 interview
# ℹ 33,582 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Unfortunately I don't have any idea to handle this error.
Is there anybody to give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Hi welcome to SO! Would you mind providing a minimal reproducible example of your data? For some examples see this link

Why don't you simply anti_join(word_space, stop_words)?  If word_space is a tibble of words, why are you trying to split it further by passing it to unnest_tokens()?  By the way, the reason for the error is that tibble(text = word_space) results in a tibble with a list column; you can avoid it by doing tibble(text = word_space[["word"]]) %>% unnest_tokens(....), but this seems duplicative as I mention above
